# What happens if I edit "/dev/sda"

Tags: encryption, usb-drive

I know what `/dev/sda` is (no need to explain), along with `sdb`, etc. But what happens if I, say, encrypt `sda`? Will that encrypt the drive it refers to? More importantly, though, could I then decrypt `sda` and the filesystem would be in one piece?

I'd edit it and find out, but I'd **really** rather not venture where I don't belong, and where I don't have full control of my computer. Additionally, if my aforementioned encryption of `/dev/sda` is a bust, what are the alternatives if there are any?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to operate against the pseudo-file `/dev/sda` and encrypt it in-place. This is a Bad Idea. You would basically be overwriting the thing you are encrypting while reading it to encrypt it. You want to encrypt the drive, not the pseudo-file. Software that encrypts the drive knows how to do so without losing data. Additionally, if you don't have full control of the computer already, then you have no business encrypting the drive, since deciding to do so is more properly the responsibility of the person or persons who does have full control of the computer.

Comment: @sentinel does it change anything if I wan't refering to a bootable USB? Additionally, I just need to know if it's possible, which I suppose it is. Also, John I was thinking block encryption.

Comment: So, what would "encrypting the drive" mean other that encryoting the data that's visible through the pseudo-file, then? And considering access to device nodes for drives is usually limited to root, they'd have to already be in control of the computer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting it is possible (I suggest doing it from something like a LiveCD instead of inside the OS you intend to modify) and booting in will just be GRUB and a pass-code prompt. Decrypting it is possible if it is a known encryption method and if the attacker is aware of how to find and decrypt certain methods. I recommend the GNU Encryptor as it is capable of using a numerical-based input to decide ow to encrypt and the code needs to be put in to be decrypted properly. Just know you may need to make sure you don't encrypt the grub section and you Should be fine. (please test in a VM to ensure that this is what you want to do.)